# How to determine a command output object?

Tags: powershell

I understand the concept of pipeline and the fact that PowerShell returns objects (as opposed to text) and commands further down the pipeline can access properties of these objects by name or value.

What I'm struggling with is - how can I find out which object (and properties) are returned by a specific PowerShell command? For example, the following is a valid PowerShell command:

```
Get-AzureVM -Name "vmname" | Select-Object name,instancesize,location
```

How do I know, without running it, that `Get-AzureVM` returns an object that has Name, InstanceSize and Location properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without running it you could use the [`Get-Command`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113309) cmdlet and query the `OutputType` property to at least get the return object type. Otherwise you can pipe it to the [`Get-Member`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113322) cmdlet to retrieve all available properties and methods which is the way I would recommend you.

```
Get-AzureVM -Name "vmname" | Get-Member
```

Comment: Using a combination of `OutputType` and `Get-Member` I can get the information I want I think, so I'll mark this as the answer...